# Delphi Flicker Free with appearence

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

If I create a simple app with a paint box and a scroll bar, draw some rectangles in the paint box, and make the scroll bar change refresh the paint box, I get a flicker free display when I drag the scrollbar (with DoubleBuffer set on the form):

```
procedure TMainForm.OnHorzChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
    PaintBox.Refresh;
end;

procedure TMainForm.OnPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
    x, y: integer;

begin
    with PaintBox.Canvas do
    begin
        Pen.Color := clBlack;
        Brush.Color := clGray;
        for y := 0 to 9 do
            for x := 0 to 9 do
                Rectangle(x * 32, y * 32, x * 32 + 24, y * 32 + 24);
    end;
end;
```

If I then change appearance to Carbon, the flicker returns:

```
program test;

uses
    Vcl.Forms,
    main in 'main.pas' {MainForm},
    Vcl.Themes,
    Vcl.Styles;

{$R *.res}

begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
    TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Carbon');
    Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
    Application.Run;
end.
```

So how can I use appearance and not get flickering? The setting double buffer on the main window doesn't stop the flickering.

Comment: You probably should not be using double buffering. You should use Invalidate rather than Refresh.  And VCL styles are flicker hell. Stop using VCL styles and all will be good.

Comment: Solution seems to be use FMX as that has flicker free graphics

Comment: Out of the frying pan and into the fire

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72558988/23233974 your solution worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your `PaintBox` on the `TPanel` and set `Panel.ParentBackground` to False. In this case it does not flicker for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which has worked for me, is removing the `seClient` flag from the `StyleElements` propery of the `TPanel` or `TScrollBox` components.